# C#で動的にSQL文を作成できないでしょうか？(Update文)

Tags: c#

Entityクラスのうち、指定のプロパティのみをupdateする
SQL文を動的に作りたいですが、何か良い方法はありませんでしょうか？
where文は外から指定する形でwhereの手前までを動的に作成したいです。
Entityの各プロパティに対して、UPDATE文の対象とするような
フラグを持たせればできますが、既存のEntityのプロパティは
変更せずにそのまま使いたいです。
カスタムAttribute等を付加することも検討しましたが、Attributeは
インスタンス生成後に変更はできないようなので、難しそうです。。
例：HogeクラスにA,B,Cプロティがあるとして、

```
Hoge hoge = new Hoge();
hoge.setB(b);
hoge.setC(c);
string sql = SqlUpdateQueryCreator.create(hoge);
```

みたいに呼んだら、sqlとして`update HOGE set B=b, C=c`を返すような
仕組みを作りたいです。この場合はAプロパティを何らかの形で
無視するようにしたいです。
なお、Entityクラスを関数に渡して、Entityのすべてのプロパティを
InsertするSQL文を動的に作成するのはリフレクションを使ってできました。
お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

Comment: Entityクラスと書かれていますがEntity Frameworkを使用しているわけではない、ということでしょうか？

Comment: フレームワークは利用していません。いわゆるPOJOのデータベースのカラムと同じ名前のプロパティを持ったEntityクラスです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression`の式木を使用すればよいと思います。例えば以下のような引数のメソッドと呼び出し方を実現できます。

```
void Update(Expression<Func<Entity>> expression);

Update(() => new Entity()
{
    B = b,
    C = c
});
```

メソッドの内部では`expression.Body`を`MemberInitExpression`にキャストして`Bindings`プロパティを参照すると各初期化子の式にアクセスすることが出来ます。
それから各`MemberBinding`の値を評価するのですが、これは

1. `ConstantExpression`にキャストする
2. `Expression.Lambda`でラムダ式の式木を作成し、さらにデリゲートにコンパイルする。
3. `ExpressionVisitor`を用いて複合的に処理する

というような方針が考えられます。以下の例ではすべての列の値を`object[]`で取り出しています。

```
void Update(Expression<Func<Entity>> expression)
{
    // SQLバッファ
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    // 値の式のリスト
    var values = new List<Expression>();

    // UPDATE文の先頭部分
    sb.Append("UPDATE [Entities] SET ");

    foreach (var b in ((MemberInitExpression)expression.Body).Bindings)
    {
        // b.Memberから列名を取得する
        sb.Append('[').Append(b.Member.Name).Append("] = ");

        // ((MemberAssignment)b).Expressionから値を取得する
        sb.Append("@p").Append(values.Count);
        values.Add(((MemberAssignment)b).Expression);

        sb.Append(", ");
    }

    // 余計な", "を削除する
    sb.Length -= 2;

    // TODO:Whereを生成する

    // 生成したSQLの表示
    Console.WriteLine("SQL:");
    Console.Write("    ");
    Console.WriteLine(sb);

    // valuesの値をobject[]として取得するメソッドを作成する
    var valueGetter = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[]>>(
                            Expression.NewArrayInit(
                                    typeof(object),
                                    values.Select(v => Expression.Convert(v, typeof(object)))
                            )
                      ).Compile();

    // valuesの表示
    Console.WriteLine("Values:");
    var actual = valueGetter();
    for (int i = 0; i < actual.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    @p{i}: {actual[i]}");
    }
}
```

なお汎用的に`WHERE`句を作成する場合は引数に`Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate`を追加しますが、これには必ず`ParameterExpression`が含まれるため、`ExpressionVisitor`を継承して

1. `ParameterExpression`への`MemberAccessExpression`はSQLフィールドに変換する。
2. 1を含まない式木は`Expression.Lambda`でパラメーター化する
3. 1と2を含む式木はSQL上の演算に置き換える。

というような処理を実装する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
b.Mmberでプロパティ名は取得できましたが、((MemberAssignment)b).Expressionでプロパティの値がうまく取得できません。
例えば、string cValue = "CCC";
Update(() => new Entity()
{
    B = "AAA",
    C = cValue 
});
とすると、Bは"AAA"　（""が付いてきます。）
Cはvalue(ここにパッケージ名+クラス名等の文字列).CCCとなります。
Bについては""を除去すれば良いと思っていますが、
Cの場合は何か良い方法ありますでしょうか？

Comment: @mame 問題の式木を適当に操作し、`Expression.Lambda`の`body`として渡すと「ラムダ式の式木」を作成することが可能です。これをコンパイルして実行すると呼び出し側から渡された値が取得できます。

Comment: 上記の方法でUpdate文の動的作成が実現できました。式木のcompile部分のパフォーマンスはどうなのでしょうか。現状速度に問題ありませんが。

Comment: @mame 平均して数msオーダーだと思いますが、初回のみ100msオーダーとかなり遅くなる可能性があります。ですがキャッシュによって回避しようとした場合、式内に自動生成型(`[CompilerGenerated]`)の定数が出現することを考慮する必要があるためかなりの手間がかかると思います。

Comment: 平均数msなら問題ないですね！数秒かかるとなると問題になりそうでしたが。